# Manage list of tags for acts-as-taggable-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm currently using acts-as-taggable-on in a project.

I can offer users the choice of only tagging new objects with existing tags by using Model.tag_count. But the client wants to be able to manage the list of available tags from the admin panel. Is this doable? Any way to create new available tags other than by attaching them to a specific model? If not, what other tagging gem/plugin would you recommend as an alternative that can support this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new table/model called Tags with a column (attribute) called `name`. Each record in this table will be a different tag. You can then create a form where the client can create a new tag by submitting the form with a tag name.

You can handle tag management using basic CRUD actions - primarily `create` and `destroy`.

Comment: Yeah, might have to resort to that -- but I was hoping to be able to integrate with an existing tagging gem.